# You or yourself

Tags: meaning, reflexives

I need some help how to write it? 
Keep the child in you! Or "Keep the child in yourself"?
I have checked some samples but I am still not sure.

Comment: What is the context for the sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

The common saying is: *"Feed/Nurture/Acknowledge your* 'inner child'.*"* (US)

Answer (score 0):

The question here is whether the objective or the reflexive pronoun is the correct choice.

In order to decide it is helpful to quote from *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p1488). In the section with the title *Object of preposition* the CGEL identifies the respective contexts in which the reflexive pronoun is *mandatory*, *optional* or *inadmissible*.

***Mandatory reflexives*** - The CGEL states:

> This represents much the most common pattern and can be regarded as
>   the default case.

and provides inter alia the following examples:

> - He doesn't look after himself.
> - She believes in herself.
> - Max had it done by himself.

In such cases the reflexive pronoun is needed to make clear that the pronoun refers back to its antecedent (i.e. that the subject and the pronoun are one and the same person.) Compare:

- He doesn't look after him.

in which the *he* and *him* would be interpreted as referring to different people.

***Optional reflexives*** - The CGEL gives the following examples, in which the prepositions "*indicate spatial locations*":

> - Rhianna saw a spider near her/herself.
> - Phil kept the radio next to him/himself the whole trip.

and states:

> There is variation across speakers and also particular examples.

***Inadmissible reflexives*** - The CGEL lists the following as examples. (The *star in the CGEL indicates ungrammaticality.)

> - She looked about her/*herself.
> - He liked having children around him/*himself.
> - They took their cousins with them/*themselves.

The CGEL states:

> The prepositions again involve spatial location ... . The complements
>   of the preposition are required to be anaphorically linked to the
>   subject, so that we can't say, with the same interpretation of verb and
>   preposition, **She looked about him*, **He liked having children around
>   me*, and so on.

Turning to the OP's two alternatives: *Keep the child in you!* or *Keep the child in yourself!* we note that the preposition is one of spatial location. And further we note that it is nonsense to talk about keeping your inner child in someone else: **(You) keep the child in me*. The complement of the preposition in this context is "*anaphorically linked to the subject*" - in other words the subject and the pronoun co-refer or are one and the same person.

Hence, finally, the reflexive pronoun is inadmissible in this context. It has to be:

> Keep the child in you.